# How to capture contents of a label to be exact header of the table

Tags: jquery

I have two `<ul>` `<li>` structures and a `table` in the middle of them, this way

```
<ul>
    <li> 
        Text <label>1#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
        <li> 
        Text <label>2#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
        <li> 
        Text <label>3#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
        <li> 
        Text <label>4#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
        <li> 
        Text <label>5#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
    <li> 
      <!-- First read that contains only label inside -->
      <label>6#</label> 
    </li>
</ul>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>#1</td>
        <td>#2</td>
        <td>#3</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
        <td>#1</td>
        <td>#2</td>
        <td>#3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>#1</td>
        <td>#2</td>
        <td>#3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<ul>
    <li>
       <label>7#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
       <li>
   <label>8#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
</li>
<li>
   <label>9#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
</li>
<li>
   <label>10#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
</li>
</ul>
```

I need to dynamically grab the first `<li>` above table that has just `<label>` tag and turns it into the title of my table. Getting the end result that way.

```
<ul>
    <li> 
        Text <label>1#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
        <li> 
        Text <label>2#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
        <li> 
        Text <label>3#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
        <li> 
        Text <label>4#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
        <li> 
        Text <label>5#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>

</ul>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th> <label>6#</label> </th>
        <tr>
   </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>#1</td>
        <td>#2</td>
        <td>#3</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
        <td>#1</td>
        <td>#2</td>
        <td>#3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>#1</td>
        <td>#2</td>
        <td>#3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<ul>
    <li>
       <label>7#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
    </li>
       <li>
   <label>8#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
</li>
<li>
   <label>9#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
</li>
<li>
   <label>10#</label> <input type="text" value="" />
</li>
</ul>
```

You can do this?...

**[DEMO CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/JoaoFelipePego/FGJLg/7/)**

Comment: if you have 2 ul, you should use $('ul').each(function() {});

Answer (score 1):

A more jQuery-ish way:

Loop through the `li` elements, find one with only 1 child, where that child is a `label`.

Build a `thead/tr/th`, append the `label`, add it to the table, and remove the `li` that used to hold it.

```
var lbl = null;

$('li').each(
    function() {
        var li = $(this);

        if (li.children().length == 1)
        {
            var labels = li.find('label');
            if (labels.length == 1)
            {
                lbl = labels;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
);

if (lbl)
{
    var text = lbl.text();
    var li = lbl.closest('li');

    var thead = $('<thead>');
    var tr = $('<tr>').appendTo(thead);
    var th = $('<th>').appendTo(tr).append(lbl);

    li.remove();

    $('table').prepend(thead);
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/FGJLg/9/

Comment: If the `li` contains text and a label, this doesn't work (it's not factoring in text, only the children that are elements)

Comment: Right. But that's not the problem we're solving.

Comment: I suppose it is and it isn't... `that has just <label> tag` vs the actual provided example table

Comment: And in case I have more than one <li> with one label. How to make it always get the above table? http://jsfiddle.net/JoaoFelipePego/FGJLg/11/ (Transforming the # 6 in the top of the table)

Comment: Updated fiddle appending all the labels to the table. You may want to change things to put them in their own rows, cells, etc. http://jsfiddle.net/FGJLg/12/

Comment: @PaulRoub In this situation I just wanted to turn the # 6 in the top of the table and the other # 5 and # 4 continue as normal.

Comment: @PaulRoub And in case I have multiple similar situations? (You have several tables with several `<li>` containing only `<label>` inside tag?

Comment: Give your `ul`s and `table`s unique IDs. Instead of `$('table').prepend()`, use `$('#tableid').prepend()`' Instead of `$('li').each()` use `$('#listid li').each()`.

Comment: Read what I wrote. Add IDs to your lists and tables. Include those IDs in your jQuery selectors just like I said.